# SBT - get path to managed jars

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, jooq

I want to use some dependencies to perform code generation in Scala.

Example:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "2.4.0"

val jooqTask = jooq := {
  val classpath = "jooq-2.4.0.jar;jooq-meta-2.4.0.jar;jooq-codegen-2.4.0.jar;."
  val main = "org.jooq.util.GenerationTool"

  "java -classpath %s %s /project/jooq-configuration.xml".format(classpath, main) !
}
```

However, I want to get the classpath of the dependencies, so I can actually run the Java process.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the classpath of your compile dependencies like this:

```
val jooqTask = jooq <<= managedClasspath in Compile map { cp =>
  val classpath = Path.makeString(cp.files))
  val main = "org.jooq.util.GenerationTool"

  "java -classpath %s %s /project/jooq-configuration.xml".format(classpath, main) !
}
```

Note that the classpath does not include "." (aka current directory), though.